# Difference between `willReturn()` and `will($this->returnValue())` in PHPUnit?

Tags: phpunit

In PHPUnit, is there *any* difference between

`$mockFoo->method('methodName')->will($this->returnValue($mockBar));`

and

`$mockFoo->method('methodName')->willReturn($mockBar);`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, `willReturn()` is just a shortcut. Before it was introduced, the other variation was the only one. Now you don't need it for this simple case.

To quote [the manual](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html):

> This short syntax is the same as `will($this->returnValue($value))`. We can use variations on this longer syntax to achieve more complex stubbing behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! That was what I was looking for. :)

Comment: @eyecatchUp Can you please mark this as the correct answer at least now