# Add value to array in Symfony TestCase class in test function if the array was initialised in setUp method

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, pass-by-reference, prophecy

Apologies if the question looks off, I am new to both Stack Overflow and php.

My class looks a bit like this:

```
final class MyClass extends TestCase
{
  private MyService $myService;
  private ObjectProphecy $object;
  private array $x;

  protected function setUp(): void
  {
    $this->object = $this->getProphet()->prophesize(MyOtherClass::class);

    $this->x = [];
    $this->object->foo()->willReturn($this->x);
  }

  public function test(): void
  {
    $this->x = [1];
    $this->myService->bar();
  }
}
```

The issue is that within the call of `$this->myService->bar();`, on the execution of `object->foo()`, I get `[]`, which was set in the `setUp()` method, and I'd like it to be `[1]` instead.

I suspect this is because `$this->object->foo()->willReturn($this->x);` makes a copy of `$this->x` and then doesn't notice the change I make later on. However, if I change `$x` to be some object instead of array, everything works as I'd expect it to work.

What would be the cleanest way of dealing with this? I was hoping for something like declaring `$x` to be pointer to array but that doesn't seem to be possible?

Comment: Use `will($this->returnValue($this->x))` instead of the shorthand. This will be evaluated at calltime.

Comment: Interestingly, if I try what you suggested, I get some type mismatch error. However, according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868479/difference-between-willreturn-and-willthis-returnvalue-in-phpunit - the two should behave exactly the same. So if I read it correctly, neither should your suggestion work, nor should I see the behaviour that I am seeing, so clearly I am doing at least something wrong.

Comment: According to the [reference](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/test-doubles.html): `Using the will($this->returnValue()) method, for instance, you can configure these dummy implementations to return a value when called.` <-- `when called`. Try using a getter here instead of the direct value.

Comment: Ok, I made a try and this is evaluated **once** at **creation time**, not every time it is called. So your first assumption that a copy is created is true.

Comment: Does my answer help you out? Would be nice to get some feedback.

Comment: Hey apologies for the delay. Thanks, looks almost certainly helpful. If I outright change `willReturn` to `willReturnReference` i get error saying it's undefined, but haven't been able to look deeply in it. I'll upvote your answer for the time being and keep you updated / mark as successful when I resolve my issue.

Comment: Oh, looks like I can't upvote since I haven't enough rep. I'll keep you updated, appreciate your effort!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. You don't need to upvote, but you may mark the answer as correct, if it is working for you.

Comment: Looks like the issue is that I am using `ObjectProphecy`, and your example is using `MockObject`. I suspect this is why outright changing to `will($this->returnValue($this->x))` as you suggested initially failed for me, and also why outright changing to `willReturnReference` failed for me. These don't exists for `ObjectProphecy`. I'll dig a bit further if what I'm trying to achieve is doable with `ObjectProphecy`, but https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy/issues/225 suggest it might not be. Would you know if this is doable with `ObjectProphecy`?

Comment: Oh, I never used that library, so I thought it would be compatible with the default MockObject class,, because it looks like it is mocking. Sorry for that misunderstanding.

Comment: That's fine, thanks for the effort! It was definitely very useful. Maybe you can add to beginning of your answer something like "According to link_i_posted it's not possible with `ObjectProphecy`, but you can do it with `MockObject` as follows..."? If so, I'd be happy to mark it as correct. Well.. That is, if you trust the link I gave enough that it's not possible :-)

Comment: Good point. The answer is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the possibility to return a reference. Tested for [PHPUnit 10.3](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.3/test-doubles.html).

### Note

This was  not tested with `ObjectProphecy` which does not seem to implement the default mocking object. So for this example code I've used the native PHPUnit `MockObject` instead.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MockObject;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

// Never used, but neccessary to have a class to be able to create a mock
class MyFoo {
    public function foo(): array
    {
        var_dump('called foo()');

        return ['foo'];
    }
}

final class ReturnTest extends TestCase
{
    private MockObject $mock;
    private array      $x;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->x = [];
        $this->mock = $this->createMock(MyFoo::class);
        $this->mock->method('foo')->willReturnReference($this->x);
    }

    public function test(): void
    {
        $this->assertEquals([], $this->mock->foo());
        $this->x = [1];
        $this->assertEquals([1], $this->mock->foo());
    }
}
```