# Symfony ObjectProphecy treats array and object differently - can't change array which was initialised in setUp method

Tags: arrays, symfony, pass-by-reference, prophecy

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77088631/add-value-to-array-in-symfony-testcase-class-in-test-function-if-the-array-was-i/77098007#77098007)

I am trying out this test code

```
<?php

use Monolog\Test\TestCase;
use Prophecy\Prophecy\ObjectProphecy;
use Prophecy\Prophet;

class MyBar {
    public int $bar = 0;
}

class MyFoo {
    public function fooArray(): array {
        return [];
    }

    public function fooBar(): MyBar {
        return new MyBar();
    }

    public function fooInt(): int {
        return 0;
    }
}

final class SimpleTest extends TestCase
{
    private Prophet $prophet;
    private ObjectProphecy $mock;
    private array $myArray;
    private MyBar $myBar;
    private int $myInt;

    public function getProphet(): Prophet {
        return $this->prophet;
    }

    protected function setUp(): void {
        $this->prophet = new Prophet();
        $this->myArray = [0];
        $this->myBar = new MyBar();
        $this->myInt = 0;
        $this->mock = $this->getProphet()->prophesize(MyFoo::class);
        $this->mock->fooArray()->willReturn($this->myArray);
        $this->mock->fooBar()->willReturn($this->myBar);
        $this->mock->fooInt()->willReturn($this->myInt);
    }
    
    public function test(): void {
        $this->myArray = [1];
        $this->assertEquals([0], $this->mock->reveal()->fooArray());

        $this->myBar->bar = 1;
        $this->assertEquals(1, $this->mock->reveal()->fooBar()->bar);

        $this->myInt = 1;
        $this->assertEquals(0, $this->mock->reveal()->fooInt());
    }
}
```

Notice the difference in test function how array `$myArray` doesn't get updated, nor does int `$myInt`, but object `$myBar` does.

- Why do they not act in the same way?
- What would be the recommended way of having the array act like the object does?

I was thinking about passing the array as a reference, but according to [this](https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy/issues/225), it might not be possible with `ObjectProphecy`. The answer to the question I linked at the top suggests the solution using another approach with `MockObject`, but I am trying to see whether there is a solution within `ObjectProphecy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are testing something completely different (comparing tomato with potato). Hopefully I have explained the situation well enough below.

To answer your first question, I used `$this->myInt` as an example (however, this also concerns `$this->myArray`);

In your `setup()` function you are using three steps:

1. **Your first step is assigning `0` to `$this->myInt`:**

   `$this->myInt = 0;`
2. **Your second step is creating an object:**

   `$this->mock = $this->getProphet()->prophesize(MyFoo::class);`
3. **Your third step (#3) is assigning the object with value `0` (from `$this->myInt`):**
   `$this->mock->fooInt()->willReturn($this->myInt);`

Then in your actual test function (`test()`):

4. **As a fourth step (#4), you are changing `$this->myInt` value to `1`:**

   `$this->myInt = 1;`
5. **As a fifth step (#5) you are actually testing the value of the `object` which according to `step #3` should still return `0`:**

   `$this->assertEquals(0, $this->mock->reveal()->fooInt());`

In the last step, you are actually comparing `0` with the value you set in `step #3` (which was `$this->myInt = 0` accoring to `step #1`). E.g. your test will **pass**. `Step #4` is not doing anything, since you are not changing the value of your object (which you are testing), you are only changing the value of the private parameter within your `class`. Your expected behaviour only works when you test the value of `$this->myInt`, so like this:

`$this->assertEquals(0, $this->myInt);`

So to solve your problem, either rewrite your test OR make sure that you are changing the correct value (either within your `class` or within the `object`).

To explain your `object` example and why this is different, you are actually changing the value within your `object` and testing the same `value` in you test (testing it correctly):

```
$this->myBar->bar = 1;
$this->assertEquals(1, $this->mock->reveal()->fooBar()->bar);
```

You changed the `value` within the `object`. Once again, your test will **pass**.

To answer your second question, change `step #4` into:

```
$this->myInt = 1;
$this->mock->fooInt()->willReturn($this->myInt);
// and then to do your test from step #5:
$this->assertEquals(0, $this->mock->reveal()->fooInt());
// this should fail.
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I suspected something like this might be the case. However, I still don't quiet understand _why_ do they don't act in the same way. You say that with `myBar` I change the value within my `object`, but I could imagine you saying that in `myArray` I change the value within my `array` (which is close enough to `object` to leave me confused still). It feels as though `willReturn` called with `int` or `[int]` stores copy of that, but when called with `myBar` stores reference (which would be fair enough since it couldn't know how to make copy of `myBar`)?

Comment: `$this->mock->fooArray()->willReturn($this->myArray);` will **NOT** return a dynamic `$this->myArray`. It **SETS** `[0]` (not `$this->myArray`) and will **ALWAYS** return `[0]`. Here `$this->mock->fooBar()->willReturn($this->myBar);` you are setting an object. It will **ALWAYS** return the object. Here `$this->myBar->bar = 1;` you actually update the value **WITHIN** an object. So this will be updated `$this->mock->reveal()->fooBar()->bar`, since you have updated the value **WITHIN** the object.

Comment: Ok, I see, this goes in line with what I thought it feels like, tnx. It does fill a bit unnatural to me that it behaves differently. Out of interest, could you point me to the part of implementation where I can this different handling of `int` vs object (`myBar`)? Like if i tested it with `string` now, I'd expect it to behave like `int`, but would be nice to know exactly where in code it treats it differently to `myBar`.

Comment: I can not example it any better than I did above. However, I tried it with code: [https://3v4l.org/bv0Z3](https://3v4l.org/bv0Z3)

Comment: Ah - thank you! Your code made me realise the issue has nothing to do with `willReturn`. Lines 98 - 108 illustrate the culprit behind my confusion. And, why those lines act the way they do, is simply because PHP assignment operator (`=`) acts in one way for `int`, `[int]` (assigns value) and in other way for objects (assigns reference). And this behaviour implies the behaviour of `willReturn` which I was confused about, failing to see reason is this simple. Thank you for all the effort - I'll mark your answer as correct. You can update it with parts of this comment if you feel it'd be useful.

Comment: I am glad the code helped understanding the difference! You are very welcome.